# Error al ejecutar php artisan migrate laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

intento ejecutar el comando "php artisan migrate" y me sale el siguiente error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fruteria_master and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

> 1   C:\xampp\htdocs\portafolio2\cursoPHPudemy\aprendiendo-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
> PDOException::("could not find driver")

> 2   C:\xampp\htdocs\portafolio2\cursoPHPudemy\aprendiendo-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
> PDO::__construct()

ya hice la conexión con la base de datos en el archivo .env con su respectivo nombre de bd su usuario y contraseña(uso workbench y ya le otorgue los permisos con el comando GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON fruteria_master.* TO ******@localhost;).

según he buscado por la web, hay que des comentar la extensión ;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll en el archivo php.ini la cual ya lo hice y no funciona.

Estoy usando laravel 8.x, php 8.0, composer 2.0.

les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: se señor.  ya reinicie el servidor(xampp)

Comment: ¿Qué pone en el archivo env en la variable DB_CONNECTION? Tienes algo mal en el driver :/

Comment: `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`
`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`
`DB_PORT=3306`
`DB_DATABASE=fruteria_master `
`DB_USERNAME=******  `
`DB_PASSWORD=******`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logre resolver el problema y les comparto. Espero les sirva:

1. en su terminal, escriba php --ini

esto generará la ruta actual del archivo de configuración php.ini.
Algo asi: (Loaded Configuration File:C:\Program Files\php-8.0.0\php.ini)

Tenga en cuenta que no es el mismo de php.ini de xampp (en mi caso). Es el de archivos de programas o program files.

2. edite php.ini con el block de notas o con el editor que quieran.
3. buscar ;extensión = php_pdo_mysql.dll y descomentelo  eliminando el punto y coma (;)
4. guarde sus cambios de php.ini
5. reinicia el servidor web para aplicar los cambios
6. Ahora ejecute su comando.

php artisan migrate

y eso es todo. A mi me funciono, espero a ustedes también

Comment: En mi caso ya tengo pdo_mysql activado y sigo teniendo el mismo problema